# How to prevent or clear the cache used by ComponentMeasurements

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, internals

Let's restart the kernel and take the first example from `ref/ComponentMeasurements`:

[image]

Timings indicate some kind of caching mechanism. It seems useful in many cases.

Not when you are trying to profile / optimize your code.

Question:

How to clear that cache so I can run a function again and get timings as it was the first time it sees that image?

---

Here's another example, which uses randomly generated input images. This way it is easy to generate a new image to run the benchmark on.

```
rim = RandomImage[1, {2000, 2000}];
testIm = MaxDetect[ImageAdjust@Blur[rim, 20], 0.02]

ComponentMeasurements[testIm, "Circularity"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.26826, Null} *)

ComponentMeasurements[testIm, "Circularity"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.078708, Null} *)
```

---

Another example, `i1 i2` are images with dimensions: `{4096, 3000}`.

[image]

Comment: Okay, `ClearSystemCache[]` doesn't make a difference here. But my guess is that the additional time at first execution is due to loading some packages and libraries, because when I repeat that with different images in the same session, this timing difference is not as severe anymore.

Comment: The first call probably has to load some library files. All calls after that seem to be fast, even for different images.

Comment: @NikiEstner I just commented the same, but it seems that there really is a timing difference: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7wAXT.png

Comment: @Szabolcs: You're right. One workaround would be to call `testIm = ReplacePixelValue[testIm, {1, 1} -> RandomReal[]];` between `ComponentMeasurements` calls, but that's a hack of course

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89002/discussion-on-question-by-kuba-how-to-prevent-or-clear-the-cache-used-by-compone).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other people have noticed, there is more to a function call than just the execution of the desired computation.
The most useful thing is to break apart all the important steps.

## Definition loading

The first thing that happens in a fresh kernel and takes a little time, is the autoloading of the definitions of symbols that have some top level evaluation semantic defined the the binary `.mx` files

```
(* In[1] *)
OwnValues[ComponentMeasurements]

(* Out[1] *)
(* >> {HoldPattern[ComponentMeasurements] :> 
  System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[ComponentMeasurements], 
    Hold[ComponentMeasurements, 
     Image`MeasurementsDump`contourMeasurements, 
     Image`MeasurementsDump`findStringSlot, 
     Image`MeasurementsDump`findNumericSlot, 
     Image`MeasurementsDump`unsupportedMeasurements3D], 
    "ImageProcessing`Measurements`MeasurementSegments`"] /; 
   System`Dump`TestLoad} *)
```

The first evaluation of `ComponentMeasurements` will trigger the ownvalue rule and load the specified file

```
(* In[2] *)
StringDelete[
 FileNames["*MeasurementSegments*", $InstallationDirectory, 7],
 $InstallationDirectory
 ]

(* Out[2] *)
(* >> {"/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/MacOSX-x86-64/ImageProcessing/Measurements/MeasurementSegments.mx"} *)
```

We can isolate this timing by evaluating the symbol alone

```
(* In[3] *)
Table[ComponentMeasurements // AbsoluteTiming // First, 5]

(* Out[3] *)
(* >> {0.004618, 0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

## Extra code loading

The first time we use a symbol as a function, more loading may happen, triggered by the downvalue code. A nice way to track that is via the `TraceLoading` utility, that will print all the symbols triggering extra loading.

```
(* In[4] *)
Get["GeneralUtilities`"];
i = Image[{{1}}];
ComponentMeasurements[i, "Elongation"] // AbsoluteTiming // First // TraceLoading

:6: "SetImage" -> "ImageProcessing`Utilities`ImageUtilities`"

:6: "MorphologicalComponents" -> "ImageProcessing`MorphOps`Components`"

:6: "Padding" -> "ImageProcessing`SpatialOps`ImagePad`"

:6: "ColorQ" -> "ImageProcessing`ColorOps`Colors`"

:6: "ContainsOnly" -> "Language`Contains`"

:6: "VectorOfImagesWithSameProperties" -> "ImageProcessing`LanguageIntegration`ImageOperations`"

:6: "Image3D" -> "ImageProcessing`ImageBasics`Image3D`"

:6: "Dataset" -> "DatasetLoader`"

"SystemFiles/Components/TypeSystem/Kernel/64Bit/TypeSystem.mx"

"SystemFiles/Components/Dataset/Kernel/64Bit/Dataset.mx"

(* Out[6] *)
(* >> 0.136793 *)
```

## Function call

The list of dependences above reminded me that `ComponentMeasurements[-image-]` needs a segmentation mask, and will call `MorphologicalComponents` if that's not provided. To build a more accurate test we should exclude that computation from the timing (or not, depending on what exactly you want to measure).

I am going to use a random image generator for this test. It is called once to again exclude potential loading times.

```
(* In[7] *)
img := Binarize[Blur[RandomImage[], 2], .55]
img;
```

Now we can finally measure `ComponentMeasurements` performance

```
(* In[9] *)
SeedRandom[1]
Module[{i, m},
 i = img;
 m = MorphologicalComponents[i];
 ClearSystemCache[];
 ComponentMeasurements[{i, m}, "Elongation"] // AbsoluteTiming // First
]

(* Out[10] *)
(* >> 0.007916 *)
```

Considering that we are cleaning the cache before every run, the subsequent timings are in line with the previous result, both on the same image and a different one.

```
(* In[11] *)
SeedRandom[1]
Module[{i, m},
 i = img;
 m = MorphologicalComponents[i];
 ClearSystemCache[];
 ComponentMeasurements[{i, m}, "Elongation"] // AbsoluteTiming // First
]

(* Out[12] *)
(* >> 0.007862 *)

(* In[13] *)
SeedRandom[2]
Module[{i, m},
 i = img;
 m = MorphologicalComponents[i];
 ClearSystemCache[];
 ComponentMeasurements[{i, m}, "Elongation"] // AbsoluteTiming // First
]

(* Out[14] *)
(* >> 0.008051 *)
```